# Why TLSWrap objects consuming memory?

Tags: node.js, websocket, v8, aws-sdk

I am using nodejs version 4.2.3, recently I observed that memory pile up quickly while uploading data to S3 bucket (Approx. file size is 1.5 GB each). I took heap snapshot which shows TLSWrap object retained size around 1GB.

Any one faced same issue ? thanks in advance.